# Algorithms in formal logic + ZFC

Tags: algorithms, proof-writing, set-theory, foundations, formal-proofs

From my understanding, most of mathematics can be built up assuming a mechanical procedure of manipulating finite strings of symbols according to certain rules. A conventional way to do it is via the ZFC language of set theory. We can start off with axioms from ZFC and first-order logic, and deduce new theorems according to mechanical procedures. These completely symbolic theorems and proofs can then be translated into natural language (say English). I understand the typical non-formal proof in math to then be a convincing argument that the formal proof can be written in formal symbols.

Now common math objects can be represented as sets (e.g. a function is a set of ordered pairs, which can be represented as sets) and thus we can prove things about them in formal ZFC. However, I've never seen any semblance of an algorithm or its proof written in formal logic. For example, consider the binary search algorithm. How would one write it in the language of ZFC? How would one prove its correctness, termination and "running time" formally (in ZFC) too? Does anyone have an example?

Comment: You would use something like Hoare Logic, and you would establish that using a ZFC construction of a computing device (such as a turing machine).  It wouldn't be trivial to construct the framework, but it would be ridiculously silly to try to prove algorithmic correctness directly with ZFC axioms rather than using an intermediary framework.

Comment: Is there any reference which shows how to construct such a framework from ZFC?

Comment: There is nothing impressive about constructing a turing machine from ZFC.  Or establishing the axioms of Hoare logic.  It is just a lot of work.  Anyone who knows the ideas could do the work, you don't need a reference.

Comment: @DanielV Would the construction be along the lines of a function from a finite state space and a line number to the same state space? Would we then reason about the function to prove things about the algorithm?

Comment: May I ask why you are asking?  You are basically saying "I want to build X" (a task that requires competence in ZFC, fundamentals of computing, and Hoare logic, not a common overlap) and even granted that you understood these things, it would still take quite a bit of time and tedium to actually construct such a thing.  Most people are simply satisfied that such a construction exists.  If you are really interested in going down this long and tedious path, I'd suggest starting with some proofs of the axioms of Hoare logic.

Comment: Would the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) be too simple an example to satisfy you?

Comment: @DanielV It might not be impressive to you :). Such an exercise could be useful to many students and people interested in logic (such as me haha). thank u for your consideration